# Como llamar a vista desde metodo de controlador en MVC Api C#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Amigos, una consulta, les comento nuevamente soy novato en MVC, estoy trabajando en un desarrollo de Login en MVC Api Web para desde otras aplicaciones web que tenemos llamar a login, enviándole el Id de la aplicación que lo llama...

Lo lleve a cabo utilizando ETF, y escribí el siguiente método que es funcional dentro del controlador **Acceso** el cual recibe ID a través de un modelo **AccesoVieModel**, y utilizando Tiddler es como verifico la recepción del id por Post observo el correcto resultado.

```
  [HttpPost]
    public AccesoViewModel VerificaAplicacion([FromBody] AplicacionViewModel model)
    {
        AccesoViewModel oR = new AccesoViewModel();
        oR.resultado = 1;
        try
        {
            using (AccesoEntities db = new AccesoEntities())
            {
                var lst = (from ca in db.catalogo_aplicacion
                           join ce in db.catalogo_estatus on ca.id_estatus equals ce.id
                           where ca.id == model.id_aplicacion
                           select new { ca.id, ca.cnombre_aplicacion, ca.curl, ca.id_estatus }).FirstOrDefault();
                if (lst == null)
                {
                    oR.resultado = 5;
                    oR.mensaje = ":-/ Caramba !, No encontre relación del ID que enviastes con ninguna aplicación registrada. Por favor verifica ID enviado."; // Si se recibe un ID que no exista de la aplicación
                }
                else
                {
                    switch (lst.id_estatus)
                    {
                        case 2:
                            oR.resultado = 2;
                            oR.mensaje = "Lamentamos los inconvenientes causados, esta aplicación esta INACTIVA TEMPORALMENTE, para mayores informes consulte con el COORDINADOR y/o RESPONSABLE de este PORTAL.";
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            oR.resultado = 3;
                            oR.mensaje = "Lamentamos los inconvenientes causados, la Aplicación se ENCUENTRA en proceso de ACTUALIZACIÓN y/o MANTENIMIENTO, consulte más tarde...";
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            oR.resultado = 4;
                            oR.mensaje = "Le informamos que la Aplicación se encuentra DADA DE BAJA, para mayores informes consulte con el COORDINADOR y/o RESPONSABLE de este PORTAL .";
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            oR.resultado = 0;
            oR.mensaje = ":-/ Caray esto no debio pasar!, ha ocurrido un error : " + ex.ToString();
        }
        return oR;
    }
```

Como podrán observar se valida el estatus de la aplicación, y tengo una vista de nombre **mensaje** *a la cual deseo llamar si la aplicación tiene un estatus diferente de 1*, *en caso contrario si es 1 mostrar index*.

Como decirle después de que valide redireccione a la vista **mensaje** o bien a **index**.

Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: En principio estás mezclando dos cosas. Una cosa es un Web API y otra es una aplicación ASP.NET MVC. Primero debes construir un cliente C# que consuma el Web API, y luego utilizar este en la aplicación ASP.NET MVC. Te recomiendo leas antes algo sobre cómo consumir una Web API [Cómo crear un cliente C# para un Web API de ASP.NET](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/10/29/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-cliente-c-para-un-web-api-de-aspnet-core-iii)

Comment: Saludos, gracias Rafael mira te comento que estoy tratando de crear un MVC Api para enviarle id de aplicación que lo llame y el MVC api se encarque de validar de credenciales del usuario y me redirija hacia la aplicación que lo llame...

Por ej. www.misistema.net/login sea llamado por www.misistema.net/inventario u otro subsitio, cabe resaltar que esta la tablita en sql server con el catalogo de aplicaciones y un campo url para a la hora de consultar tener la url a donde redireccionar.

Comment: Actualizando información...

Seguí ejemplos de videos pero mi inexperiencia no visualizo que yo no necesitaba devolver un modelo, si no una vista.

Ahora bien, me sucede una situación extraña, si le digo al método que será un ActionResult me obliga a usar using System.Web.Mvc; y el HttpPost lo tengo que usar ahora: [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost] en lugar de usar [HttpPost], y si uso View dentro del método en el controlador, me indica que "el nombre View no existe en el contexto actual". Gracias.

Comment: Como ya te indiqué estás confundiendo los términos y las tecnologías. En principio, no existe un "MVC Api", o es un Web API o es un ASP.NET MVC. Tu no puedes redirigir desde un Web API a una Vista, las redirecciones se hacen en aplicaciones Web MVC. Te aconsejo leas y aprendas más acerca del tema antes de emprender un proyecto de esa categoría.

Comment: Gracias Rafael, tienes absoluta razón... dentro de mi imaginación pretendía hacer un login a llamarse desde otras aplicaciones, he trabajado con web form y para cada proyecto siempre tenía que incluir el login, tengo una BD exclusiva para usuarios, y al emigrar a MVC  me emocione y pensé erróneamente con web api, amigo Rafael por favor iluminame con tu experiencia. Lo que pretendo hacer como se haría, te comento ya diseñe el login dentro de la solución, me funciona pero es como trabajaba antes, pretendo diseñar un Login a ser llamado desde cada aplicación que tenga...